# Is possible to install an Android app on web server?

Tags: android, web

Is it possible to install an Android app on a web server? So i can use the application on a web browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: google before so please

Answer (score 1):

You can host an emulator in wab container and access app through emulator
http://android-emulator.org